# Is there anyway to get string value from md5 hash using some salt?

Tags: hash, md5, salt

Let me describe the scenario:

I know the hashed string, and the $salt, but not the $pass. md5 format is:

```
md5($salt.$pass)

example value = ae10f955a7164ba6905919e7798284ca

here $salt = q)SDs
$pass is unknown.
```

Now, is there anyway to get **md5($pass)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of brute force techniques, no.  However brute force is a valid approach.  Depending on the scope of this problem, you have a few options:

- Write a small program to compute MD5 hashes of md5(salt + random string).
- Use an existing cracking tool like [John the ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/).
- Build a [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) using the salt, and then use that to find the appropriate password.

A tool like John the Ripper may be the easiest place to start.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to recreate the password using a variety of methods, it's really not the purpose of the hash. The hash is supposed to encode the string in question in an irreversible way, so people who somehow get a hold of the hash cannot just reverse the encryption and have the password in their hands.

So no, it really isn't possible...at least not in any easy way.